# Java look into API method

Tags: java, api, methods

Is there a way to look into originally given methods by API?
I am a beginner in programming and sometimes feel like taking huge shortcuts when using given methods and not really having an idea what tools i would use if i had to write it on my own.

Thanks in advance for given advices.

Comment: maybe i didnt ask well, what i mean is for example: i use method reverse for Collections, it works well and does it job, BUT is it somewhere visible from background, like what VM does while executing it (iterating through elements and creating some list to be able to reverse the one i want to).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to look into Java code?

Here is a snapshot to attach java **documentation** and **source code**

1. Click Windows
2. Click Preferences
3. Click Java
4. Click Installed JRE

See the image for more steps

[image]

Comment: and for those who installed it like @Noor Nawaz showed, then in eclipse when holding **ctrl + LMB** on some class in code you can directly jump to its source code

Answer (score 0):

After you clarified your question, I think I can suggest you a solution. 
 Let's suppose that you want to see what java.util.Collections.reverse(List list) do!
 When you downloaded the JDK you downloaded the sources too. You can find it here (or else to where you placed) for example for JDK8: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_66 => src.zip
 In this zip file you can find \java\util directories and inside this you can find Collections.java and inside this you can find the reverse(List list) method in JAVA source format.
 (Anyway, you can find the bytecode of this example method too in the rt.jar...but I think you shouldn't bother yourself with it if you are a beginner.) 
 I hope I could help.